# classTag scala using map

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a function that uses classTag instead of explicitly define the data type of an input parameter.

For example,

```
def getColMult[T: ClassTag](A: Array[T], cols: Array[Int]): Array[Array[Double]] = {
    if (cols.size == 1) {
        var C = Array.apply(A.map{_(cols(0))})
        C.transpose
        }
    else {
        var C = Array.apply(A.map{_(cols(0))},A.map{_(cols(1))})
        for (i <- (2 to cols.size - 1)) {
            C = C ++ Array(A.map{_(cols(i))})
        }
        C.transpose
    }
}
```

Upon running the function, this would get this error:

Name: Compile Error
Message: :35: error: T does not take parameters
var C = Array.apply(A.map(_(cols(0))})

console:39: error: T does not take parameters.
var C = Array.apply(A.map{*(cols(0))}, A.map{*(cols(1))})

Comment: What are you trying to do with that line?

Comment: I am trying to get a specific column from an Array[Array[Double]] A. If I have to get only one column, I use this line A.map{_(cols(0))} outputting an array of double corresponding to that column. In order to make it as array of array, I have to use the apply function in scala. If I have multiple columns to obtain, I have to use loops.

Comment: But `T` is not necessarily an `Array`. So all the compiler knows is that the `_` within `A.map(...)` could be anything.

Comment: Could you replace the image with text?  That makes it easier to index.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `_()` with `_.apply()`, the error gets clearer:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object Foo {
  def getColMult[T: ClassTag](a: Array[T], cols: Array[Int]): Array[Array[Double]] = {
    if (cols.size == 1) {
      val c = Array(a.map({_.apply(cols(0))}))
      c.transpose
    } else {
      val c = Array(a.map({_.apply(cols(0))}), a.map({_.apply(cols(1))})) ++
        (2 to cols.size - 1).flatMap({ i =>
          Array(a.map({_.apply(cols(i))}))
        })
      c.transpose
    }
  }
}
```

Gives you

```
test.scala:6: error: value apply is not a member of type parameter T
      val c = Array(a.map({_.apply(cols(0))}))
                            ^
test.scala:9: error: value apply is not a member of type parameter T
      val c = Array(a.map({_.apply(cols(0))}), a.map({_.apply(cols(1))})) ++
                            ^
test.scala:9: error: value apply is not a member of type parameter T
      val c = Array(a.map({_.apply(cols(0))}), a.map({_.apply(cols(1))})) ++
                                                        ^
test.scala:11: error: value apply is not a member of type parameter T
          Array(a.map({_.apply(cols(i))}))
```

Btw, that code looks functionally equivalent to

```
def getColMult2[T: ClassTag](a: Array[T], cols: Array[Int]): Array[Array[Double]] = {
  val c = cols.map({col => a.map({_.apply(col)})})
  c.transpose
}
```